# Ruby on Rails: How to fetch and display descendent records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a parent model that has many children:

```
class Band < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :concerts
end

class Concerts < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :band
end
```

Now I would like to display them in my index view, but I can't figure out the syntax for displaying the children records:

```
<% @bands.each do |band| %>
  Band name: <%= band.name %>
  Concerts:
  <ul>
    <% @bands.concerts.each do |concert| %>
      <%= concert.location %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting an error like `undefined method 'concerts' for #<Array:0x00000102c537f0>`. What is the proper way for fetching and displaying the descendent models?

Comment: how do you get `@bands`? did you restart your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close, but you need to change `@bands.concerts.each` to `band.concerts.each`.

```
<% @bands.each do |band| %>
  Band name: <%= band.name %>
  Concerts:
  <ul>
    <% band.concerts.each do |concert| %>
      <%= concert.location %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```